# Return fetch_object from self class PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a login class what checks if all fields are correct, and if is it then proccess.

My code: (`login.php`)

```
<?php
require('sql.php');

class login {

    private $user;
    private $email;
    private $doc;
    private $password;

    function login($field, $pass){
        $user = $field;
        $email = $field;
        $doc = strtoupper($field);
        $password = $pass;

        $this->getUser($user, $password, $r) ? $r : $this->getEmail($email, $password, $r) ? $r : $this->getDoc($doc, $password, $r) ? $r : null;
    }

    private function getUser($u, $p, &$r){
        global $sql;
        $count = 0;
        $check = $sql->query("SELECT ... ");
        while($row = $check->fetch_object()){
            $count++;
            $r = $row;
        }

        $count == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    private function getEmail($e, $p, &$r){ same as getUser()... }

    private function getDoc($d, $p, &$r){ same as getUser()... }
}

?>
```

Now in Index (index.php)

```
<html>

ALL HTML STUFF WITH THE FORM

</html>

<?php

require('login.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $login = new login(trim($sql->real_escape_string($_POST['user'])), md5(trim($sql->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']))));
    if($login != null){
        echo "SUCCESSFUL: ".$login->user;
    }else{
        echo "INCORRECT PASSWORD";
    }
}

?>
```

The idea is get `$login` values like `$login->user`. But show me an error...
How can I do this? Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is that md5 call you have in there? It's kinda scary

Comment: Also saying there is "an error" is not a sufficient problem description

Comment: You should return `$this->getUser($user, $password, $r) ? $r : $this->getEmail($email, $password, $r) ? $r : $this->getDoc($doc, $password, $r) ? $r : null;`

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors',1);ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);error_reporting(-1);` on top of your code then tell us what is the error. And whats the point with your getEmail / getUser /getDoc method ? It gets nothing, just check if true or false ... Why dont you use only one request in constructor to get all the informations ? (Oh, and `$r` is never declared)

Comment: The error what show me is Fatal error: Cannot access private property login::$user

Answer (score 1):

This give you error because of  private $user;

Make it public $user; because private member are not allowed to access from outside

or you can do some like following

```html
public function getUsername(){
  return $this->username;
}
```

and access it via echo $Obj->getusername();

Comment: Thanks for answer sagar, but i need to return $r value, because getUser function checks if username and password is correct and then volcate all the information to $r value.

Comment: What is contained in `$r` ? I dont get the point to create an object and not set all its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I m not saying all of this is working. Is just to get an idea of what i mean.

What you want is to get user informations.
For that you have created a class `login`.

Why dont you just create a `User` class where you retrieve and store your informations.

If constructor get an error. Just return `null`.

```
class User {

    private $user;
    private $email;
    private $doc;
    private $password;

    private $detail1;
    private $detail2;
    private $detail3;
    private $detail4;    

    public function __constructfunction login($field, $pass){
        $user = $field;
        $email = $field;
        $doc = strtoupper($field);
        $password = $pass;

        $error = false;

        //Detail for User
        $count = 0;
        $check = $sql->query("SELECT ... WHERE username='.$this->user.' AND pass = '.$this->password.'");
        while($row = $check->fetch_object()){
            $count++;
            $r = $row;
        }

        if($count == 1)
        {
            $this->detail1 = $row['detail1'];
            $this->detail2 = $row['detail2'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = true;
        }

        //Detail for Doc
        $count = 0;
        $check = $sql->query("SELECT ... WHERE username='.$this->user.' AND pass = '.$this->password.'");
        while($row = $check->fetch_object()){
            $count++;
            $r = $row;
        }

        if($count == 1)
        {
            $this->detail3 = $row['detail3'];
            $this->detail4 = $row['detail4'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = true;
        }

        if(true === $error)
            return null;
    }

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->doc;
    }

    public function getDoc(){
        return $this->doc;
    }

    //Maybe not usefull
    public function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ThinkTank, i'm not trying to return private $user value.
Before i was using a simple function to check username.
in the while($row = $check->fetch_object()){$r = $row;}.
That mean $r value have all SQL values in fetch_object() function.

Comment: I'm sorry but yes you are trying to return it here : `echo "SUCCESSFUL: ".$login->user;`. Ok, thank I know $that `$r = $row` but what is it supposed to store ? User details ?

Comment: Exactly, apologize me for the example. I'm trying to show users details whats have to store in $r

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everyone but i solve the problem!!

in the constructor of login i put one value more.

```
public function login($field, $pass, &$r)
```

then in index.php

```
$login = new login(//user, //pass, $r);

echo "SUCCESSFUL: ".$r->user;
```

This return me the value from SQL query. This is what i was looking for.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please check my answer. Because the way you are working is really really bad ... POO is here to help you. You are using it only as a procedural way... Its really weird.

Comment: In your code i will have to declare all table field (sql) what i'll use, in this case i use 3 tables to check users login. So i think my way is enought for my case. Anyway thank you.